# Using SASS in a team where not everyone has the Mindscape extension installed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, sass

I have a huge MVC project which i wanna use SASS in. I can't really change its structure so the solution I've been using is Mindscape.

Mindscape is great because it runs the SASS watcher behind the scenes and lets me edit my SASS files, compiling it on the fly into my Styles directory (also: it comes with a compass support).

The problem is that people who don't have this extensions now manually have to install it, because it's not a part of Nuget's dependency manager. I have 2 questions:

- Is it possible to auto install Mindscape upon build, as if it's a dependency?
- If that's not possible, what can I use in order to compile my SASS files as I save them so that the output will go to a different folder?

I've seen [an extension](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Bundler#installing-the-run-on-save-vsnet-2010-extension) for this, but it's for VS *2010* and not 2012.

Comment: instead of relying on an add-in, you should probably include something like [`SassAndCaffee.AspNet`](http://nuget.org/packages/SassAndCoffee.AspNet/) and leave compilation to the site. otherwise, you're going to have to well document that you can't make any changes without an extension to your VS. [Which, IMHO, shouldn't be the case--I should never have to install something to work on a project]

Comment: SassAndCaffee.AspNet was option #2, however i can't change the structure of my code for the time being. It's already has a bundler that includes files from specific folders into specific pages so what i want, is that bundler to get my compiled SCSS.

Comment: So what about a [Sass Bundle Transformer](http://nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.SassAndScss/1.6.6)? refactor it a bit to use make Sass feasible through bundles and minification

Comment: [Web Workbench](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2b96d16a-c986-4501-8f97-8008f9db141a) works just fine in VS 2012. Doesn't seem like too much of a hardship to install given all the advantages of Sass.

Comment: I've managed setting up sass as a part of the project in various ways, however, Compass - which gives SASS very powerful features, still requires and external ruby build. Since we have various CI processes which must work hand in hand, and since porting the entire Compass lib into the project sounds like an overkill, we will use mindscape for the local dev, and set up a builder on our remote servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed setting up sass as a part of the project in various ways, however, 
Compass - which gives SASS very powerful features, still requires an external ruby build.

Since we have various CI processes which must work hand in hand and since porting the entire Compass lib into the project sounds like an overkill,

we will use [Mindscape](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2b96d16a-c986-4501-8f97-8008f9db141a) for the local dev, and set up a SASS builder on our remote servers.

Comment: Just to add to this - Web Workbench Pro comes with command line versions of the core for use in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to just not let everyone edit sass/css and keep its maintenance isolated to the front-end devs :)

Compiled css files can be then added to version control next to their sass source - so that *everyone* can run the website locally with most recent styling and *front-end devs only* can edit the source however they want. This also removes the need to have sass compilers on deployment servers which may be a dealbreaker depending on infrarstructure's willingness to maintain such tools.

This is not a perfect way to deal with the problem but, compared to the overhead of having everyone run sass locally, it's the lesser of two evils. After initial setup of protocol, this has been working out for us so far (large .NET dev shop)

P.S.: I'm considering switching to .less just because then everyone could use [dotless](http://www.dotlesscss.org/) with [combres](https://github.com/buunguyen/combres) so that there is no dependancy on third party tools. Lack of compass-like toolkit is not a dealbreaker for me, but your situation could be different

Comment: I think that Compass is what makes SASS so powerful, otherwise, it doesn't matter. So you could say it's a deal breaker, thanks for the advice though!

Comment: @Mike86: compass [does](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/10/04/compass-for-visual-studio-with-web-workbench/) work with mindscape - but yeah, the other approach is for more trivial pre-processing usage only.

Comment: Yeah, it does, hence it's the most reasonable solution. Gotta run the compass updater manually on build which isn't that great, but it's the best solution at the given moment.